# Hybris swagger UI date-time example format

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, sap-commerce-cloud, springfox

I have a project with Hybris and we are providing a restful API throught swagger + swagger-ui. We have a problem with the format of the date-time attributes and params. It is shown with this format: "2018-06-22T08:00:19.130Z".

However, the format that we use and need to shown in the examples provided in the swagger-ui is "2018-06-22T08:00:19Z".

The params are DTO's autogenerated by spring.

Any idea on how to change the format of the date-time for the examples?

Thanks,
Cris

Comment: Can you share your swagger.json?

Answer (score 3):

This is highly dependent on what version of swagger-ui you have, the examples were not always supported, so my example below is assuming you are on the latest and greatest *(if not you should consider upgrading)*.

If you need to show it in a query parameter you need to set the value in the default:

```
      "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "data.d1",
        "in": "query",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time",
        "default": "2018-06-22T08:00:19Z",
      }
```

And for definitions is just `example`:

```
"definitions": {
 "Data": {
  "properties": {
    "date0": {
      "example": "2018-06-22T08:00:19Z",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    }
```

Here is how something like that will look like

[image]
Here is the link to the live version:
http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/swagger_51019812.json#/ApiExplorer/ApiExplorer_Get